# Whats the diffrence between numpy.resize() and cv2.resize()?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library

Im having an image as input, and need to resize it. I have earlier used pillow to do this but the library wasnt available where i needed it.  np.resize(image, (50,50)) returns a different array then cv2.resize(image, (50,50)) and (pillow) Image.fromarray(image), image_from_array.resize((50, 50)).
Wondering whats the difference between these methods.

Comment: Have you read the respective docs?  But if you need to ask, I'd say don't even pay attention to `np.resize`.  It's not suitable for images.

Comment: IIRC opencv has `width X height` and numpy has `row X column` so they are opposite of eachh other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`np.resize` doesn't 'resize' images, instead it interprets the data that's already there in a different way. E.g. say you have four integers `[1, 2, 3, 4]`, then `.resize((2, 2))` will give you `[[1, 2], [3, 4]]`.

Use `cv2.resize` if you actually want to resize an image.